# Border size as 0.667 when set the border width as 1px in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

**In FireFox browser alone ,** i get the border size as 0.6667 when i set the border width as 1px to the div or input element or any HTML element. Please find the below screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I have given the border in css inline style and also via separate class but i get the same result. i have not provided any box model to the element.

If i given the border size 2px then its working fine. i get problem on providing odd number.

if i give 1px => 0.6667
if i give 3px => 2.6667

[image]
[image]

Due to above problem, my calculation get breaks in css level. So can you please provide solution to resolve this issue?

Whether its browser issue? or else provide any work around solution on this?

Thanks,
Gobalakrishnan

Comment: Are you zoomed out in your browser?

Comment: Is your zoom level set to 100%? Press ctrl + 0

Comment: browser is not zoomed ... 100% only @JonUleis

Comment: I'm thinking it could have to do with the box-model.  Try display:block on the same element.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgxq56s9/) gives me 1,1,1,1 for the calculated border. [Screenshot of the fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGQ5H.png). So we need some more info. What system, what version of the browser, are you using libraries such as Bootstrap etc.

Comment: @MrLister  But i got the same 0.667 value as border size in the provided fiddle also. Please find the my Firefox details.    Firefox 54.0.1 (32 bit) browser is not zoomed.

Comment: @MrLister can you please share your browser version details also?. Am using windows 10 with firefox 54.0.1 (32 bit)

Comment: My screenshot was with SeaMonkey 2.48 (64 bit) on Debian KDE, but it works the same with Firefox 55.0.2 (64 bit) on Windows 8.1 or the Firefox Developer Edition 32 bit. 1 whole pixel only. Sorry.

Comment: Same thing happens for me in Firefox 58.0.2. Frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and it happens even on the latest Chrome on Windows

I found that it's because I use a high-resolution monitor and set the "scale"
to 150% in the "Display Setting", if I set the scale to 100%, the 1px works well.

Similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718300/3983650

Answer (score 0):

Until Mozilla gets their shit together you can use inset box-shadows instead:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(#f00, 1);
```

In that case, remember to add padding to compensate accordingly.