# Uneven border to html table rows at different zoom level

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html table on my web page, given `border-collapse: collapse;` but at some rows border-bottom seems more highlighted and for some rows its less highlighted.

and highlighed rows change if we change the the zoom level.

**At zoom level 100% it looks like below**

[image]

**Observation:** 3rd row top border is more black than rest of rows border

---

**At zoom level 125% it looks like below**

[image]

**Observation:** 1st, 2nd & 3rd rows borders are more highlighted (black) than rest of rows border

---

**Note:** initially i thought it was some problem with my application css, but then i checked on w3school.com same behaviour reproduced for table on below page

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_collapse

**Check and run below code snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Uneven border </h2>
<p>you can see some borders are more highlighted than others and if we zoom the webpage then it might change the highlighted row borders.</p>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproductible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can identify the problem ?

Comment: @Cédric added code snippet

Comment: I read that it seems to be a bug in chrome and edge, but works in firefox, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829918/17684809) (check the comment as well)